# Case statement from a BO variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have a variable in BO which calculates any repairs that are over £240

This is called **Sum diff**

```
=Sum([REP Invoice Cost Amount])-([REP Original Estimated Cost Amount])ForEach ([REP Invoice Cost Amount];[REP Original Estimated Cost Amount])
```

and then another variable which adds another calculation

```
=If[Sum diff]>=240 Then "Y" Else "N"
```

What would the case statement equivalent of this be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

IN SQL `case`

```
CASE 
   WHEN [Sum diff] >= 240 THEN 'Y'
   ELSE 'N'
END as fieldName
```

Comment: Hi sorry BO is for business objects. A variable is the equivalent of an expression in SSRS so the [Sum diff] is the actual name of the variable.